# Updating point geometry based on geometry of another feature class using arcgisscripting?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-9.3, cursor

I'm looking to update the point geometry of lets say "oldFC" by obtaining the shape geometry of "newFC" and applying that to the "oldFC".  I also want it to grab the value in the ID field in "newFC"and use that to search for the same ID in "oldFC" and then set the shape value.

I believe I have the loop set up and it appears to be grabbing the ID just fine but it doesn't update the shape geometry.

I'm very much a beginner with using Python so my code is rough.

Here's the code snippet...  running 9.3 (no access to 10):

```
rows = gp.SearchCursor(newFC):

row = rows.next()


gp.MakeFeatureLayer_management(oldFC, oldLayer, "")
gp.MakeFeatureLayer_management(newFC, newLayer, "")

while row:

newgeo = row.getValue("Shape")
newID = row.getValue("ID")

print newgeo
print newID

where =  "ID" + '= '   + str(newID) #my sql expression

print where

new_rows = gp.UpdateCursor(oldFC, where)
new_row = rows.next()
while new_row:
    new_row.setValue("Shape", newgeo)
    new_rows.UpdateRow(new_row)
    new_row = new_rows.next()
row = rows.next()
```

Comment: 9.3, 10, feature class... may I guess this is about that ArcGis thing?

Comment: Yes, sorry I should have mentioned that.

Comment: you should take caution using the ESRI id to grab matching features. There are many esri functions on any esri resource which will re-write the FID or OID or other internal esri ObjectID.    http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgiSDEsktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=About_ObjectID_fields  explains some of the basics about oids. and the following from edn   http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/NET/a3af4514-7a6a-4c05-b26d-942d717d09a3.htm

Comment: I actually am using a "managed" ID that is used on the data and not the ESRI id your referring to.  But thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You won't want to use the setValue method to set geometry.  It should be:

```
new_row.shape = newgeo
new_rows.UpdateRow(new_row)
new_row = new_rows.next()
```

Comment: When I modified that line I get this error   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Shape'

Comment: A couple of things come to mind.  First, try setting newgeo = row.shape in the top part of your script.  Second, are you setting your geoprocessor object to run against 9.3 (gp = arcgisscripting.create(9.3))?

Comment: the newgeo = row.shape worked perfectly.  There is also a typo in my original code..  for new_row = rows.next() it should be new_row = new_rows.next().  Thanks to everyone for the help!